When a client needs to upgrade it's Dotnet version (Minor version)?
recently A question has been bothering me and I haven't found an answer about it. We are developers and after some of VS 2022 versions, it automatically updates our dotnet version. For example, 8.0.7 -> 8.0.8 and so on. My projects are ASP.Net Core. My question is, does my clients need to upgrade their dotnet (hosting bundle) version? what are the effects of upgrading and not upgrading dotnet for clients? We publish new versions sometimes, but all of them are dotnet 8 and it is working. should I upgrade their dotnet versions too?
let's give you an example:
I am working on dev pc with dotnet 8.0.8 and the time where we installed project on customer server, the latest dotnet was 8.0.1. now we are upgrading dotnet always and on each update, we are publishing on newest one. but the client machine has left on 8.0.1. so does this affect something?
Thank you

If you mean dotnet tool, it's just a tool, not a runtime, so you don't need to worry.

I point that I exactly mean Dotnet Hosting Bundle! my projects are asp.net core web apps.

it's a good idea to upgrade the server's .NET version/run-time for security reasons.  I don't believe you need to touch the ASP.NET Core Module so you could probably just upgrade the latest run-time on the server(s) if you didn't want to install the full bundle.

Your .NET application, built with version 8.0.8, should run on any runtime version from 8.0.1 to 8.0.8 without issues. The .NET Hosting Bundle and .NET runtime are responsible for running your web applications on the server. The updates from 8.0.1 to 8.0.8 are generally patch updates, which include security fixes, bug fixes, and minor improvements. Therefore, you won't face any issues running your application on a server with version 8.0.1, even if it was developed with 8.0.8.
However, it is recommended to keep the .NET Hosting Bundle on client servers updated to ensure security. While you don't need to update immediately after every release, regularly scheduled updates are advisable to maintain the security and stability of your application.
